# Помогите оптимизировать код, превышен лимит времени

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
spisok, dic, num_of_words = list(), dict(), int(input())
for i in range(num_of_words):
    spisok.append(input().lower())


def test(a, b):
    return len(a) == len(b) and all(t in b for t in a)


for element in spisok:
    for element1 in spisok:
        if test(element, element1):
            if element in dic:
                dic[element].append(element1)
            else:
                dic[element] = [element1]
spisok1, spisok2 = list(), list()
for key, val in dic.items():
    spisok1.append(sorted({key, *val}))
for j in spisok1:
    if j not in spisok2:
        spisok2.append(j)

for elem in spisok2:
    print(*elem)
```

Дело в том, что я делаю тест слов на анаграммность (дается n слов и нужно разбить на группы анаграммности, вложенные циклы for пробегают по всем элементам полностью(создает одни и те же пары несколько раз), из-за этого превышается лимит времени, помогите оптимизировать циклы)

Comment: создайте массив пар слово - отсортированные буквы в слове. Теперь, используя отсортированные буквы как ключ, объедините в группы. Сложность будет n*log n, что значительно быстрее Вашего подхода

Comment: Не могли бы вы наглядно продемонстрировать, не совсем уловил?

Answer (score 1):

я не программист на питоне, поэтому сам код может быть не совсем питонный. Но ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from collections import defaultdict

# просто сортирует буквы в слове
def srt(w):
    t = sorted(w)
    return "".join(t)
# исходные слова
ws = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "oof", "bra"]
mr = defaultdict(list)
# для каждого входного слова ищем ключ - отсортированные символы
for w in ws:
    sw = srt(w)
    # и добавим в нужный бакет
    mr[sw].append(w)
# все, готово, просто выводим красиво результат
for w in mr:
    print(f"word {w}, count {len(mr[w])}")
    print("\t", end="")
    for cw in mr[w]:
        print(cw, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 0):

Более компактная запись. Плюс сортирует анаграммы лексикографически и выводит только их (слова не имеющие анаграммы пропускаются).

```
anagrams = {}
for word in sorted(input().lower() for _ in range(int(input()))):
    sorted_word = ''.join(sorted(word))
    anagrams[sorted_word] = anagrams.get(sorted_word, []) + [word]

for words in anagrams.values():
    uniq_words = set(words)
    if len(uniq_words) > 1:
        print(*sorted(uniq_words))
```

Comment: Запись через `.get` прикольная, я сам её люблю, но не происходит ли в этом случае копирования списков? Это очень неэффективно, `.append` был бы быстрее, думаю.

Comment: @CrazyElf Согласен, такая запись работает существенно медленнее, чем вариант через `anagrams.setdefault(sorted_word, []); anagrams.append(word)` или через классическую проверку на существование через обычный `if sorted_word in anagrams:`. Но на небольших объёмах данных обычно это не критично.

Comment: Если в моем коде поудалять комментарии и некоторые другие строки (шангбенг), то Ваш код не будет таким уж и "компактным". Если почитать оригинальный вопрос, то там проблема не в компактности, а в скорости...

Comment: @GrAnd У автора упирается в лимит времени, значит надо весь код делать максимально эффективным

Comment: @CrazyElf у автора реализация через алгоритм с квадратичной сложностью, вот и не проходит по времени. После оптимизации алгоритма остальные микрооптимизации уже дают микроскопический эффект.